# Instantiate class on variable declaration or within constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the “proper” place to initialize class variables in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105081/where-is-the-proper-place-to-initialize-class-variables-in-as3)

I was wondering if anyone knows wether its better to instantiate class on it's variable declaration or within a constructor?  For example, this:

```
protected var _errorHandler:ErrorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
```

or this:

```
protected var _errorHandler:ErrorHandler;

public function someClass() {
_errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
}
```

A small point I think, but I want my code to robust and efficient as possible!

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Although about Java, this should answer your question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292363/choosing-when-to-instantiate-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292363/choosing-when-to-instantiate-classes)

Comment: Thanks that answers my question, I like the point of instantiating as soon as a variable is declared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialization in the constructor is preferred, for readability--for being able to easily see what gets initialized when. The least readable option would be to mix these, which I can't recommend.

There is a third option that you will see AS3 programmers use:

- No initialization in the variable declarations
- Empty (or nearly empty) constructor
- All initialization done in one or more dedicated init() functions

This approach has two things to offer:

1. You can easily reset the object for re-use by calling init again
2. You can get around the limitation that AS3 does not let you overload the constructor like other similar languages (Java/C++/C#). You might want to, for example, be able to initialize a data structure with one or more different types of objects.

As far as performance goes, I believe your two examples would compile down to the same byte code. The AS3 compiler makes a special class initializer for *static* declarations that are outside the constructor, but for regular member variables initialized at declaration time, I expect it just moves the initializations to inside the constructor for you. But does it move them ahead or after what is explicitly in the contructor? I don't remember, which is why I cite readability as a main reason to put everything in the constructor yourself :-)

Comment: Good answer, although my preference is to initialize with the declaration unless the object is not certain to be used.

Comment: +1 for use of init() pattern. I use it in all cases.

Comment: I agree mostly, however, initialization of an object it's quite often different from resetting it. In terms of performance, is much more costly to recreate all objects rather than setting them to their initial state. Also, some objects inside the reseated class   don't need to be set to their initial state at all.

Comment: @mindnoise: I agree. This is why I tried to avoid absolutes in my description (e.g. "nearly empty" constructor). There is of course no one right answer for all classes, and if there was, it would be much harder to make a decent living as a software engineer! There are certainly cases where the most efficient way to re-use an object is to break the initializations into more than one function, for example a "one time" init (which may very well be your constructor) and a "re-init" function that only resets what is necessary.

Comment: thanks as I don't really like having any code in the constructor the extra init solution seems like a good idea, particularly for readability if performance isn't affected.